# Loading content before button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I'll try and explain this as best I can. I have a CSS card that will flip when a button is pressed. The problem I'm running into is when that button is pressed and the card flips there is a moment where the content is blank before popping up. I believe I should be looking at a way to preload this content before the button is pressed so that it exists in cache before the event takes place.

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
             <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/team/thumb.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="user">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/team/member.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="main">
                                <h3 class="name">Team Member</h3>
                                <p class="profession">Position</p>
                                <p class="text-center">"Some Content Text"</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer">                        
                                <button class="btn btn-simple" onclick="rotateCard(this)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Manual Rotation
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end front panel -->
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h5 class="motto">"Some Content Text"</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="main">
                                <h4 class="text-center">Job Description</h4>
                                <p class="text-center">Some Qualifications</p>                                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-simple" rel="tooltip" title="Flip Card" onclick="rotateCard(this)">
                                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Back
                            </button>
                            <div class="social-links text-center">
                                <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end back panel -->
                </div> <!-- end card -->
            </div> <!-- end card-container -->
        </div> <!-- end col sm 3 -->
<!--         <div class="col-sm-1"></div> -->
        </div> <!-- end col-sm-10 -->
```

CSS

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.card-container {
      -webkit-perspective: 800px;
   -moz-perspective: 800px;
     -o-perspective: 800px;
        perspective: 800px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card-container:not(.manual-flip):hover .card,
.card-container.hover.manual-flip .card{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
-moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
 -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}


.card-container.static:hover .card,
.card-container.static.hover .card {
    -webkit-transform: none;
-moz-transform: none;
 -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.card {
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s;
     -o-transition: -o-transform .5s;
        transition: transform .5s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
   -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
        transform: rotateY( 180deg );
        z-index: 3;
}

.back .btn-simple{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
}
/*        Style       */


.card{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #444444;
}
.card-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.card .cover{
    height: 105px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.card .cover img{
    width: 100%;
}
.card .user{
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    margin: -55px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
}
.card .user img{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
}

.card .content{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}
.card .content .main {
    min-height: 160px;
}
.card .back .content .main {
    height: 215px;
}
.card .name {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.card h5{
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.card .profession{
    color: #999999;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.card .footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.card .footer .social-links{
    font-size: 18px;
}
.card .footer .social-links a{
    margin: 0 7px;
}
.card .footer .btn-simple{
    margin-top: -6px;
}
.card .header {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 90px;
}
.card .motto{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .stats-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.card .stats{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .stats:first-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.card .stats:last-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.card .stats h4{
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .stats p{
    color: #777777;
}
/*      Just for presentation        */

.title{
    color: #506A85;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
    line-height: 90%;
}
.title small{
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
.space-30{
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
.space-50{
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
.space-200{
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
.white-board{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 60px 60px 20px;
}
.ct-heart{
    color: #F74933;
}

 pre.prettyprint{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.atv, .str{
    color: #05AE0E;
}
.tag, .pln, .kwd{
     color: #3472F7;
}
.atn{
  color: #2C93FF;
}
.pln{
   color: #333;
}
.com{
    color: #999;
}
```

JS

```
function rotateCard(btn){
        var $card = jQuery(btn).closest('.card-container');
        console.log($card);
        if($card.hasClass('hover')){
            $card.removeClass('hover');
        } else {
            $card.addClass('hover');
        }
    }
```

It should also be mentioned that I am building this behind WordPress so if there is a plugin that will make the job easier I'm also open to that idea. TIA

Comment: Where does your content come from? The database? An external API? Can it be hardcoded into the HTML?

Comment: Currently all of the content is hardcoded into my HTML (see above). It will eventually be pulled from custom fields but regardless the styling still does not load prior to the click.

Comment: Data from custom fields is coming from the database. On page load, retrieve this information via PHP and echo it into the page, then you won't need to worry about fetching the data on click (as Filippo also suggested on his answer below.)

Comment: I edited the above a bit to better show the issue since I don't think I am being very clear. The script simple waits to apply the hover animation until after the button is clicked. The problem is not that the content isn't loading as it is currently hardcoded and exists when the page loads. The problem is that the styling is not loaded until the button is clicked so the animation begins but the styling and content both appear a second after the animation has finished (or so it appears). This leaves a blank space during the animation. Hopefully that clears up confusion, sorry!

Comment: I just tried your code (had to make a couple of changes as it initially didn't work as is) and I don't see what the problem is. See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/u25cf9ht/

Comment: Same problem with your code. On initial page load, the first time you click to flip the card it is blank and then the content appears. Only happens the first time because it caches everything after that

Comment: On which browser(s) (and OS) are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: Looks like it is only happening on Chrome, I feel kind of dumb that I didn't check this before. What is it about Chrome that does this? I'm not as worried about it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196279/discussion-between-redpanda-and-cabrerahector).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you start the request to get the data when clicking the card, you can try starting when the mouse gets over it using jQuery's `hover()` function. If you want you can unload the data when the mouse stops hovering, too. If it's still too slow the only option I can think of is preloading.